# How crawlers/bots work? differentiating bots/crawlers http requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, search-engine, google-search

I am working on one website.

I need to find out if my website gets a visit from Google's or any other search engine's `crawlers/bots`

In my application, I am intercepting http requests. And need to find out if crawlers/bots are making http requests to crawl my site.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can check the User-Agent header: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17096/how-can-i-identify-that-my-page-is-requested-by-robot-but-not-users-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the user agent string to see if it's a known robot. An example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("Googlebot"))
            {
                //it's one of the google robots
            }
            else if (...)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

For google, the list of agents they use can be found here [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943).

Others, you'll have to find out yourself.